# NodeJS express - What is the difference and correct way of creating a basic server

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference and what is the most correct and latest way when creating a server with nodejs express?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
console.log('server running')
});
```

and the second way

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app)

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
console.log('server running')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of correctness, there is no difference, express basically does what you're doing in the second example when `app.listen` is called.

Check out the [source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L616)